# Binary convert Int to Float in Kotlin

Tags: type-conversion, kotlin

I want to handle a value that has been read from file as 4 byte integer as if it was a 4 byte IEEE Float and convert it into such a variable. 
Are there any experiences, how this can be done in Kotlin in an easy and elegant way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`java.lang.Float.intBitsToFloat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#intBitsToFloat-int-).  Note that this assumes a particular (though conventional) bit layout - see the [docs for the inverse (`floatToIntBits`)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#floatToIntBits-float-) for details.

Example:

```
import java.lang.Float.intBitsToFloat

// ...

val x = 0x4D8EF3C2
println(intBitsToFloat(x))  // 2.99792448E8
```

<sup>[Live demo.](https://ideone.com/KH2u7C)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

In the meantime, Kotlin has implemented a standard function for this that works across platforms: fromBits().

Documentation here: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/from-bits.html

In Kotlin/JVM, it uses the java.lang.Float.intBitsToFloat mentioned in the other answer.

Answer (score -1):

It‘s not the answer of  this question , but might help the others that need just simple convert.
In Kotlin simply convert Int to Float :

1- Add F or f to the end of Integer number:

```
val result = 123F
```

or

2- Use toFloat() :

```
var result =  ( intWidth * intHeight ).toFloat()
```

Comment: Yeah I read it, but I looked for converting the Int to Float & here was the only post! Nevertheless  it doesn’t related to the answer you need, so It might help the others that need just simple convert.